# Onload focus issue

Tags: javascript, html

I have a small task, where there is a drop down list in the page and when select on of that dropdown it redirects to the other page where it has some information and there is one button when clicked it moves to the previous page and it should focus om the drop down. When I use onload function everytime I reload the page it is focusing on the dropdown but I want that only when the button is clicked and the page is reloaded. Can anyone help me with this issue ? Thanx in advance

Comment: [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Could you use a cookie to determine which code to run?